# storing a calling session from php file

Tags: php, html, session

I'm trying to create a php file that will store data from an html file and another html file to call that data from the php file.

In my first html file, I have buttons that will go to the second html file. Depending on which button I press, I want to show the name of the what i stored in the button.

In the second html file, I have a button to destroy that data so if I wanted to press the other button, will show that name instead of the first button I pressed.

So for example, in login, I want to log in as John and have catalog show that i logged on as John. Once I hit the log out button, I want to then log in as Ben and do the same thing.

How would I do that? would I use a session for that?

EDIT: I updated my files and this what each of them look like

login.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="createsession.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="buttonName" value="John" >
</form>
</body>
```

catalog.html:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>catalog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Catalog</h1>

Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["buttonname"]; ?>.<br>

<form action="sessions.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>

</body>
```

createsession.php:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        $_POST["buttonName"];
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['buttonName'];
        header('Location: catalog.html');
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do.

Login.html

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="createsession.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="submit" value="login" >
    </form>
  </body>
```

You were trying to POST the submit button value which after much trial and error, i've found out that you can't do. Therefore, ive made an input text box for which the user can enter a name. You then post that the same way you tried with the submit.

Then...

createsession.php

```
    <html>
<body>
<?php
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    if(isset($username))
    {
        session_start();
        #Store username as part of the session
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 

        header('Location: catalog.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo("invalid username");
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Create the variable username in which you will store the POST information from the input text box called username.
I did a small bit of validation for you also, checking to see if the user actually entered anything and if they did, it creates a session using that data and redirects them to the catalog, otherwise, just echos out invalid.

Finally
catalog.php

Because you are using php tags in the catalog, it needs to be a .php not .html.
You need to use start session again to continue the session on this page and then echo the username out as you attempted to before.

```
     <html>
 <?php
    session_start(); #Continues session from previous page
 ?>
<head>
    <title>catalog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Catalog</h1>

<?php
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
?>

<form action="login.html" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```